# How many ways to order a string of characters

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given 1,000,000 characters which can each be A, B, C or D, what is the probability that there will be 250,000 A's, B's C's and D's in any order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N=250000$.  There are $4^{4N}$ strings of $4N$ characters, each of which is equally likely, on the assumption that the four letters are themselves equally likely.  There are $${4N\choose N,N,N,N}={(4N)!\over N!N!N!N!}$$ such strings in which each character occurs $N$ times, so the probability is $${(4N)!\cdot4^{-4N}\over N!N!N!N!}$$  By Stirling's formula, as $N\to\infty$, this is asymptotic to 
$${(4N)^{4N}e^{-4N}\sqrt{8\pi N}4^{-4N}\over\left(N^Ne^{-N}\sqrt{2\pi N}\right)^4}=
{\sqrt{8\pi N}\over 4\pi^2N^2}=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(\pi N)^{-3/2}$$  When $N=250000$ this is approximately $1.0159\cdot10^{-9}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that each letter has the same probability of ocurring.

So the probability of a letter being $A$ is 0.25 and the probability of having exactly $250000$ $A$s is:

$P_1=\begin{pmatrix}
    1000000 \\
    250000 \\
    \end{pmatrix}*0.25^{250000}*0.75^{750000}$

Now $given$ that we have exactly $250000$ $A$s, the probability of having $250000$ $B$s as well is:

$P_2=\begin{pmatrix}
    750000 \\
    250000 \\
    \end{pmatrix}*(\frac{1}{3})^{250000}*(\frac{2}{3})^{500000}$

And finally $given$ that we have exactly $250000$ $A$s and $B$s, the probability of having $250000$ $C$s as well is:

$P_3=\begin{pmatrix}
    500000 \\
    250000 \\
    \end{pmatrix}*0.5^{250000}*0.5^{250000}$

So the final answer is:

$P(whatYouAreAsking) = P_1*P_2*P_3$

which will actually be a "very small" number.